# Sleeping between meat and milk

Tags: halacha, time, meat-and-milk, sleep

I have heard in the name of the Chasam Sofer that if one sleeps after eating meat that they can be lenient in the amount of time one would normally wait between eating meat and milk. Is this written anywhere? Which other poskim discussed this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The sefer "Zikaron L'Moshe" ([pg. 65](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38601&st=&pgnum=155)) writes that the Chasam Sofer originally understood that the reason one must wait six hours after meat, is because that is how long it takes to digest the food, and therefore this only applies to one who ate a meal in the day. However, when one sleeps the food digests quicker, and he may eat milk even before six hours are up. Based on this reasoning, the Chasam Sofer prepared himself a cup of coffee to drink, but when he picked it up the cup broke and the coffee spilt, which the Chassam Sofer took as a Divine sign that he was incorrect and the full wait time applies even after sleeping.

For additional sources that discuss this see: [Piskey Teshuva 3:285](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1757&pgnum=230), [Da'as Kedoshim YD 89:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6812&st=&pgnum=77), [Beis Avi 3:108](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=892&pgnum=406), [Teshuvos Vehanhagos 1:431](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20025&st=&pgnum=303)

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8836/759

Comment: Amazing find! Tell me something: in the parenthesised section that interrupts that narrative, the author mentions having found certain relevant information "בסידור הגדול דהתניא זי"ע". The Tanya?? Is he referring to the siddur of the Baal haTanya, and referring to its author as "the Tanya"?

Comment: @ShimonbM I find it much more likely that he is refering to [תניא רבתי](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/8920).

Answer (score 2):

I heard that Rav Elyashiv zt"l held this way, and that it was halakha l'maaseh for him because he slept for less than six hours.

Comment: Did he also regularly eat meat right before bed and drink milk right upon awaking? Unlikely...

Comment: @DoubleAA what does "regularly" have to do with it? If he once in his life went to a late night chasuna and wanted coffee when he woke up, it would be "l'maaseh for him"

Comment: "The Steipler Gaon is quoted as remarking that this leniency is the exclusive domain of Rav Elyashiv, as most people sleep six hours a night and he only sleeps three hours nightly."
http://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/5206

Comment: @YEZ I assumed the unique thing about RYSE was that he apparently slept less than 6 hours on a regular basis. Almost everyone in the world has on one occasion slept less than 6 hours due to a late night X so that doesn't seem so special.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the previous comment from Rentsy makes this a moot discussion - if he only slept 3 hours regularly, that gives a nice 3 hour window to have had fleishigs before going to sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Rav Eliyashiv (Ashrei HaIsh page 45:25 held that if one slept for 3 hours one can eat chicken right away. However ,he notes that this leniency only applies to chicken and a sleep during night time. This would not work for meat of a beheima. He adds ,that if one ate hard cheese one can rely on this leniency even if they slept during the day time.

Text of Ashrei HaIsh:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. Not because of the sleeping thing per se but just that he was willing to say enough chumras on top of chumras and you don't always have to be strict for the longest amount of time on every possibly meaty food. If only people were so makpid on dinim deorayta the way they are for this minhag.

Comment: Like the famous saying goes if only the aseres hadibros were givin over as minhagim