# Waking up fleishig

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, sleep

I once heard that you cannot wake up in the morning being fleishig, meaning if you go to sleep for the night, even if you sleep less than 6 hours (or whatever time you wait), you are pareve and can eat milchigs when you wake up.

What is the source for this and what is the reasoning?

Comment: Could you add "Is this true?" to your set of questions? It sounds dubious to me.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I could, but I heard it from a Talmud chochom.  Do I need to add that?  I don't doubt that there is such an opinion.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I've seen the opinion in print (now I have to remember the name of the sefer but it was of 20th century vintage). Whether or not is the halacha is a different question, but I can attest that it does exist as well.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8161/waiting-less-time-on-shavuos

> The Satmerer Rebbes (R' Yoel) said that one can drink milk in the
> morning after 5 hours from eating meat at night if he slept in
> between. R' Dov Berish from Biala said one can eat milk in the
> afternoon after 5 hours from his meat meal if he slept

Answer (score -2):

I've heard this from unlearned people only. I assume they are mixing themselves up with keilim. That is, in the idea of nosein taam lifgam, we say the blios in a kli become no longer considered halachicaly viable, bidieved at least, after being in the kli over night or over a 24 hour period. The popular opinion is to hold 24 hours but the other opinion held simply passing of the night counts. I think this is where the mistake you mention comes from.

Comment: What's the evidence for overnight being sufficient for nosein taam lifgam?

Comment: @Avrohom Yitzchok what do you mean evidence? Its a shita in the rishonim just like 24 hrs. In fact its not so nidcha from halacha in the achronim, I just don't have the time to check up what I would say off the cuff so I'm not going to.

Comment: Another duplicate!! ....consider reading the accepted answer to the [original](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27813/5323) before moving this answer there.